# Fastest recursive FFT in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am processing maps created from drone photos for a precision agriculture application that analyzes tree orchards with 10,000 trees using an IronPython 2.7 script in Rhino 6.  I use an FFT to determine the spacing, or pitch, of the trees in the Y&X directions. For the FFT, I started with a 25 May 2015 StackOverflow post of a recursive FFT that will run in Python 2.7 by Mike Muller,

```
def fft(x):
    N = len(x)
    T = exp(-2*pi*1j/N)
    if N > 1:
        x = fft(x[::2]) + fft(x[1::2])
        for k in xrange(N/2):
            xk = x[k]
            x[k] = xk + T**k*x[k+N/2]
            x[k+N/2] = xk - T**k*x[k+N/2]
    return x
```

which works pretty well.  After playing with the code for some time, I got just over a 2X speedup with this code:

```
from cmath import exp, pi

# Create dictionary for lookup of exp term.
def make_wm(N):
    global Xwm
    Xwm = {}
    for i in range(N.bit_length()-1,0,-1): Xwm[N] = exp(-2j*pi/N); N //= 2

# FFT
def fft(x,N):
    N2 = N // 2
    if N > 2: x = fft(x[::2],N2) + fft(x[1::2],N2) # When N == 2, x = [x[0],x[1]] is processed below. Thus fft is never called with N = 1.
    wm = Xwm[N]; w = 1 # Get initial exp value from dictionary lookup.
    for k in xrange(N2): # This loop is executed a total of 0.5*N*log2(N) times.
        kn = k + N2
        xk = x[k]
        t = w*x[kn]
        x[k] = xk + t
        x[kn] = xk - t
        w *= wm # Use multiply to generate subsequent exp terms.
    return x

# From the main code, fft is called with:
    N = len(X)
    make_wm(N)
    F = fft(X,N)

# Note: 1 FFT can transform 2 real-data inputs by interleaving the inputs and separating the output:
    X = map(complex,yi,xi)
    N = len(X)
    make_wm(N)
    F = fft(X,N)
    # Separate two complex outputs of length N/2 from the N-terms in the FFT result.
    yfft,xfft = separate_output(F)
```

This version eliminates half of the recursive calls and removes the slow exp and power (T**k) calculations from the fft code. Since the pitch in both the Y&X directions are needed and the input data to the FFT for this calculation is real-valued,  I got another 2X speedup by using one FFT to transform both the Y&X data sets at the same time by interleaving the Y&X data sets using:

```
# Interleave two real-data inputs.
X = map(complex,yi,xi)
```

and then the FFT result is separated into the Y&X components using:

```
# Separate two N/2-point ffts from one N-point fft.
def separate_output(X):
    N = len(X)
    N2 = N // 2
    # Extend X by copying 0th term to Nth entry so that extracting DC term (k=0) does not cause overflow.
    X.append(X[0])
    # Separate 2 ffts.
    G = [(X[k].real + X[N-k].real + 1j*(X[k].imag - X[N-k].imag))/(2.*N) for k in xrange(N2)]
    H = [(X[k].imag + X[N-k].imag - 1j*(X[k].real - X[N-k].real))/(2.*N) for k in xrange(N2)]
    return G,H
```

I do not have access to numpy's FFT in Rhino 6's IronPython which would be much faster.

My Questions:

- Is there a way to further speedup the fft in Python 2.7?
- Would a non-recursive version be faster?
- Does someone have code for a split-radix FFT which could have about 2/3 as many operations?

Comment: Why can't you use numpy's fft? A way to speed it up is to write it in C/C++: https://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/index.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I completely agree with dyukha, if you need speed do it in C; I would still look at translating with [pypy](https://pypy.org).

Comment: I use McNeel's Rhino 6 program for my work.  It supports IronPython 2.7.8. but not numpy.  I have integrated DLL's in C# for 300X speedup but their overhead is not free.  I am looking for another 2-3X speedup.  This would shrink the FFT overhead to about 15% of the overall time to generate a conformal mesh model of an orchard.  This model enables accurate measurement of the tree height, volume and yield which are valuable to tree farmers.  So before biting the bullet and going the DLL route, I was hoping to find this speedup in IronPython 2.7.8.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) solution (often preferable to [cython](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/)),
then post a separate question showing where the bottleneck has moved to.

Comment: Numba is not available in Rhino 6.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I did some research on the split-radix FFT (SR-FFT) and found an interesting paper by Anthony Blake et.al. titled: "Fastest Fourier Transform in the South"
https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ihw/papers/13-AMB-IHW-MJC-FastFourier.pdf . This paper outlines ways to speed up FFT's using SR-FFT and references Blake's Ph.D. dissertation: https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ihw/PhD_theses/Anthony_Blake.pdf .  This contains C-code for a SR-FFT in Listing 25 of Appendix B which is shown below:

```
typedef complex float data_t;
#define W(N,k) (cexp(-2.0f * M_PI * I * (float)k / (float)N))
data_t *LUT1;
data_t *LUT3;
void splitfft(data_t *in, data_t *out, int log2stride, int stride, int N) {
    if(N == 1) {
        out[0] = in[0];
    }else if(N == 2) {
        out[0] = in[0] + in[stride];
        out[N/2] = in[0] - in[stride];
    }else{
        splitfft(in, out, log2stride+1, stride << 1, N >> 1);
        splitfft(in+stride, out+N/2, log2stride+2, stride << 2, N >> 2);
        splitfft(in+3*stride, out+3*N/4, log2stride+2, stride << 2, N >> 2);
        {
            data_t Uk = out[0];
            data_t Zk = out[0+N/2];
            data_t Uk2 = out[0+N/4];
            data_t Zdk = out[0+3*N/4];
            out[0] = Uk + (Zk + Zdk);
            out[0+N/2] = Uk - (Zk + Zdk);
            out[0+N/4] = Uk2 - I*(Zk - Zdk);
            out[0+3*N/4] = Uk2 + I*(Zk - Zdk);
        }
        int k;
        for(k=1;k<N/4;k++) {
            data_t Uk = out[k];
            data_t Zk = out[k+N/2];
            data_t Uk2 = out[k+N/4];
            data_t Zdk = out[k+3*N/4];
            data_t w1 = LUT1[k<<log2stride];
            data_t w3 = LUT3[k<<log2stride];
            out[k] = Uk + (w1*Zk + w3*Zdk);
            out[k+N/2] = Uk - (w1*Zk + w3*Zdk);
            out[k+N/4] = Uk2 - I*(w1*Zk - w3*Zdk);
            out[k+3*N/4] = Uk2 + I*(w1*Zk - w3*Zdk);
        }
    }
}
void fft_init(int N) {
    LUT1 = malloc(N/4 * sizeof(data_t));
    LUT3 = malloc(N/4 * sizeof(data_t));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N/4;i++) LUT1[i] = W(N,i);
    for(i=0;i<N/4;i++) LUT3[i] = W(N,3*i);
}
```

With some effort, I was able to translate this to Python and get it working.  Then I made some changes to speed it up in Python: (1) The N== 1 and N ==2 cases at the start are replaced with N == 4 and N == 8 cases in order to reduce the number of recursive calls by 75% and the number of loops by about 8%. (2) As in my prior post above, successive twiddle factors in the loop are generated by multiplication. (3) This then enabled the use of a dictionary, as in my original post, to store the pre-computed twiddle factors which reduced their number from N/4 to log2(N)-2 and sped up their generation. (4) The out array was eliminated by reusing the input array by proper ordering of the terms generated by the N == 4 and N == 8 cases and by using list slicing in Python which creates new objects. (5) The 2 variables, stride & log2stride, were removed to simplify the Python implementation. The combination of the better SR-FFT algorithm and the Python code optimizations resulted in a 1.66X speed up over the FFT in my original post.  This is the resulting Python code:

```
# Create twiddle factors for split-radix FFT.
def fft_init(N):
    global wm,w1a,w3a
    wm = {}
    for i in range(N.bit_length()-2,1,-1): w1 = exp(-2j*pi/N); wm[N] = [w1,w1*w1*w1]; N //= 2
    w1a = (0.7071067811865-1j*0.7071067811865); w3a = (-0.7071067811865-1j*0.7071067811865)
# Split-radix FFT.
def fft_sr(x, N):
    if N == 4: return [x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3], x[0]-x[2]-1j*(x[1]-x[3]), x[0]+x[2]-x[1]-x[3], x[0]-x[2]+1j*(x[1]-x[3])]
    if N == 8:
        x0   = x[0] + x[4]; x0m  = x[0]  - x[4]; x2 = x[2] + x[6]; x2m = x[2] - x[6]
        Uk0  = x0   + x2;   Uk1  = x0m   - 1j*x2m
        Uk20 = x0   - x2;   Uk21 = x0m   + 1j*x2m
        Zk0  = x[1] + x[5]; Zk1  = (x[1] - x[5])*w1a
        Zdk0 = x[3] + x[7]; Zdk1 = (x[3] - x[7])*w3a
        Zsum0 = Zk0 + Zdk0; Zdif0 = 1j*(Zk0 - Zdk0); Zsum1 = Zk1 + Zdk1; Zdif1 = 1j*(Zk1 - Zdk1)
        return [Uk0 + Zsum0, Uk1 + Zsum1, Uk20 - Zdif0, Uk21 - Zdif1, Uk0 - Zsum0, Uk1 - Zsum1, Uk20 + Zdif0, Uk21 + Zdif1]
    N2 = N >> 1; N4 = N2 >> 1
    x = fft_sr(x[::2], N2) + fft_sr(x[1::4], N4) + fft_sr(x[3::4], N4)
    w1m,w3m = wm[N]; w1,w3 = 1.,1.; N3 = N2+N4
    for k in xrange(N4):
        kN2    = k+N2; kN4 = k+N4; kN3 = k+N3
        Uk     = x[k];         Uk2  = x[kN4]
        Zk     = x[kN2]*w1;    Zdk  = x[kN3]*w3
        # Z butterflies
        Zsum   = Zk + Zdk;     Zdif = 1j*(Zk - Zdk)
        x[k]   = Uk  + Zsum; x[kN4] = Uk2 - Zdif
        x[kN2] = Uk  - Zsum; x[kN3] = Uk2 + Zdif
        w1 *= w1m; w3 *= w3m
    return x
```

From the main code, this is called with:

```
    N = len(X)
    fft_init(N)
    F = fft_cp(X, N)
```

and as before two real-data inputs can be combined and separated to perform 2-FFTs with one call.

This answer nearly meets my goal for a 2X speed up over my original post.  I would very happy for an even better answer that gets the improvement over the 2X threshold.

Comment: Do not vandalize your own post. I'm sorry that you did not receive an answer as you were hoping, but it's just as helpful to others when you solve a problem yourself and share your solution.